# P4merge as Git Merge tool

Tags: git, git-merge, p4merge

I followed the config steps to get P4Merge set as my Git merge tool in Windows.  But, unlike when I used Beyond Compare, P4Merge pops up a window asking for the two files to compare when I have merge conflicts.  Beyond Compare automatically opened the app with the file selected, then once a file was merged, would open the next file, until all were complete.  Can P4Merge do this?  If so how?

I'm using the latest version of Git and P4Merge.

My config is:

```
[merge]
    tool = p4merge
[mergetool "p4merge"]
    path = C:/Program Files/Perforce/p4merge.exe
[mergetool]
    propt = false
[diff]
    tool = p4merge
[difftool "p4merge"]
    path = C:/Program Files/Perforce/p4merge.exe
[difftool]
    propt = false
```

Comment: Yes p4merge can do this. You said you set it. Could you show your config?

Comment: Updated the original question to include my config.

Answer (score 2):

Not a real answer but what works for me:

```
[merge]
    tool = p4merge
    guitool = p4merge
[diff]
    guitool = p4merge
[mergetool "p4merge"]
    cmd = \"C:/Program Files/Perforce/p4merge.exe\" \"$BASE\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$MERGED\"
    path = C:/Program Files/Perforce/p4merge.exe
[difftool "p4merge"]
    path = C:/Program Files/Perforce/p4merge.exe
    cmd = \"C:/Program Files/Perforce/p4merge.exe\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
```

Comment: I've seen this mentioned on various web sites and have tried it.  Unfortunately, I still get prompted for the files when I do this.

Comment: @Todd Perhaps you have a config specific to the current repository. `git config --show-origin` could help you diagnose that...

Comment: Interestingly, I tried Diffmerge instead of P4Merge and it worked fine using the config that failed for P4Merge.